# Retrofit nested array param

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this kind of API, how to implement it in retrofit?

```
{{url_product}}/en/product/lists?search[0][search_column]=group&search[0][search_condition]=like&search[0][search_text]=minyak&search[0][search_operator]=and&search[1][search_column]=category&search[1][search_condition]=like&search[1][search_text]=rempah
```

Comment: That's a Get URL so its better you build it separately . Looks like a filter URL . Create a class which will handle the building URL .

Comment: @ADM gimme the code brother